# python excel expand rows based on match

Tags: python, excel, vba, openpyxl

i am struggling with the following issue. I have 2 excel sheets.
In the main excel sheet is a receipt number for a order. In the other excel sheet are all the shipping numbers belonging to that order.

It may look like this

```
Name:                    Receipt No.:
a                        1234
a                        5678
c                        9101
...                      ...
```

The other excel containing the shipping numbers and is sorted by receipt. Multiple shipping numbers can belong to one receipt and not every receipt number here is guarenteed to exist in the other excel.

```
Receipt No.:             Shipping No.:
1234                     00000000001
1234                     00000000002
5678                     00001325687
9101                     00145489475
...                      ...
```

My goal is to extend the first excel sheet with the shipping numbers in a new column and add the rows as necessary. I tried solving this with openpyxl in python but I encountered problems rather quickly.

For what I tried so far, i gathered all the receipt numbers in a new list. Since they are sorted, every repeating match with the cell I am looking at should just be added as a new row but because I am extending the rows with `sheet.insert_row()` things start to go out of sync in my for loops and rows are added seemingly at random. How should I go about solving this?

Code wise I tried something among the lines of:

```
# Loop through first excel sheet
for i in range(1, sheet.max_row):

    # Loop through the second excel receipts which has been gathered as a list
    for j in range(0, len(receipt)):

        # If they match add the shipping number in the next column
        if sheet["B" + str(i)].value == receipt_from_first_sheet[j]:
            sheet["C" + str(i)].value = shipping_from_first_sheet[j]
             
            # If the next value in the list also matches, add a row and paste it
            if sheet["B" + str(i)].value == receipt_from_first_sheet[j + 1]:
                sheet.insert_rows(i + 1)
                sheet["C" + str(i + 1)].value = shipping_from_first_sheet[j]
```

Comment: This is really something you should do in a database using a JOIN. But, assuming the number of records is fairly limited, you can do it in Python using a dictionary or a library like Pandas.

Answer (score 1):

Use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/)

```
import pandas as pd

# df1 = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', usecols=['Name', 'Receipt'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame([('a', 1234), ('a', 5678), ('a', 9101)], columns=['name', 'Receipt'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([(1234, 1), (1234, 2), (5678, 1325687), (9101, 145489475)], columns=['Receipt', 'Shipping'])
df_out = df1.join(df2.set_index('Receipt'), on='Receipt')
df_out['Shipping'] = df_out['Shipping'].apply(lambda x: str(x).zfill(11))
df_out.to_excel(...)

print(df_out)
    name  Receipt  Shipping
0    a     1234  00000000001
0    a     1234  00000000002
1    a     5678  00001325687
2    a     9101  00145489475
```

Comment: I haven't used pandas before so your code is a bit confusing to me. Would it be possible for you to explain/show to me how to read in the excel file?

Comment: @Slevin I add pd.read_excel example to answer. I don't know exactly your file, see doc and examples https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html or search internet/stackoverflow.